# Qt QAction Plastique Check mark style

Tags: c++, css, qt

I've got a QMenu that has some QActions in it. I'm using the Plastique style, and now all of the check marks on the QActions have a grain background.

Is there a way to get rid of this?

[image]

I'm on Qt 4.8 and using redhat Linux.

Comment: This should be closed unless improved. It's missing the Qt version and the operating system, which are fundamental to know why you get that result. In any case, a quick Google search would have come up with [Qt stylesheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)

Comment: I updated it but none of the selectors on that page work